# Respostas assíncronas angular 4

Tags: ionic, ionic3, angular

Estou fazendo uma requisição, e estou esperando um retorno, porém ele é assincrono, pode demorar ou não, no meu caso so quero exibir uma mensagem na tela.

Horas ela enviar `undefined` e horas me retorna a mensagem correta.

Preciso ter certeza que esta mensagem exista como fazer isto ?

```
this.loginprovider.validaLogin(user).subscribe(data => this.response = data);
if(!this.response.sucesso){
  this.showAlert("ERROR!",this.response.mensagem);
}
```

Como ter esta certaza ?

Um detalhe:

Estou desenvolvendo um app hibrido utilizando a versão mais recente do ionic (ionic 3) e do angular (angular 4);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta colocar o tratamento dentro do retorno:

```
this.loginprovider.validaLogin(user).subscribe(data => {
    this.response = data;
    if(!this.response.sucesso){
      this.showAlert("ERROR!",this.response.mensagem);
    }
});
```